# Can I change my .gitignore at a remote site and will it push to GITHUB repro when I do a git push?

Tags: git, github

My .gitignore looks like this:

```
# Ignore
bin/
obj/
node_modules/
angular/
angular-ui-router/
packages/
*.css
*.css.map
*.js
*.js.map

# Do not ignore
!gruntfile.js
!gulpfile.js
```

I would now like to put all the css, css.map, js and js.map to my GITHUB repository. Is this possible by just removing those lines from the .gitignore? When I do a commit and push, will that new .gitignore be pushed to the GITHUB repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove those lines from the `.gitignore`, *and* add and commit your css files in your local repo.

Then you can push those files (the updated `.gitignore` and the css files now committed)

Comment: Thank you. If I just do an add with "git add ." then will that pick up on the files that were previously not part of the repo?

Comment: @SamanthaJ yes, as soon as you modify (in your local repo) the `.gitignore` (no need to add/commit the `.gitignore` yet), a `git status` should show you all the files now not ignored, ready to be added. A `git add .` will add everything (the modified `.gitignore` and the newly un-ignored files)